# Install PHP OAuth Extension In Snow Leopard

Tags: php, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, oauth

I am trying to install the PHP OAuth extension in Snow Leopard, I'm using the bundled Apache Web server and PHP 5.3.2 by Apple, which is working just fine.

When I type in Terminal:

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

oauth-1.0.0.tgz downloads fine, but then I get this error:

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update  
downloading oauth-1.0.0.tgz ...  
Starting to download oauth-1.0.0.tgz (42,834 bytes)  
............done: 42,834 bytes  
6 source files, building  
running: phpize  
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory  
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory  
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory  
Configuring for:  
PHP Api Version:  
Zend Module Api No:  
Zend Extension Api No:  
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I really have no idea this means or how to fix it, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remind myself:

1. Install all of Xcode
2. Download the PHP source
3. Go to `source-dir./etc/`
4. Copy the `/pcre/` dir. in to: `/usr/include/php/ext/`
5. Copy `pcre.h` from `/usr/include/php/ext/pcrelib/` in to: `/usr/include/php/ext/`
6. `sudo pecl install oauth`
7. Add `extension=oauth.so` to `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

Also you can install PHP with Pear using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install php70 --with-pear [--with-apache]
```

And then install oauth:

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

It automatically adds the `extension=oauth.so` to `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be fixed by [installing a newer version of pcre](http://lupomontero.com/installing-phps-oauth-pecl-extension-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.